# How to disable system audio enhancements using webRTC?

Tags: html, audio, webrtc, noise-reduction, echo-cancellation

On different systems (Windows/Android/etc.) there are some "built-in" audio enhancements. For example AEC (autmatic echo cancellation), NR (noise reduction) and Automatic Gain Control. Everyone can have those turned off or on in any combination.

There are also audio enhancements on some browsers (i know about Chrome and Firefox)

#### It is possible to turn them **all** off using webRTC?

For all I know, it is possible to turn off those "browser enhancements" and I think I managed it by specifying mediaConstraints. Example for Chrome:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: {
        echoCancellation: { exact: false },
        googEchoCancellation: { exact: false },
        googAutoGainControl: { exact: false },
        googNoiseSuppression: { exact: false },
    }
}
```

Can't find solution to turn off system/device-specific audio enhancements.
There is similar question: [WebRTC - disable all audio processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936416/webrtc-disable-all-audio-processing), but I think it addresses only those browser enhancements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Auto Gain Conctrol with WebRTC App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326846/disabling-auto-gain-conctrol-with-webrtc-app)

Comment: Note you won't need the `goog` prefixes anymore if you use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), as these were [standardized](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/) recently.

Comment: @jib Thanks for information about prefixes. 
I think this possible duplicate adresses **browser** auto gain control. I renamed question, so that it states clearly that what I need is disabling **system** audio enhancements.

Comment: This is the only microphone control surface in WebRTC.